# Complicated JavaScript string removal/replacement

Tags: javascript, regex, query-string

I have a query string that I need to remove a certain parameter from. For instance, my query string may be `"?name=John&page=12&mfgid=320"`, and I need to remove the "page" parameter from it and end up with `"?name=John&mfgid=320"`. I cannot assume that the "page" parameter is or isn't followed by other parameters.

All my attempts at using JavaScript functions/regex are failing miserably, so I could really use a hand in getting this working. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you can share your previous attempts so that we don't duplicate your effort? [mcve].

Comment: humour us with your failed attempts.

Comment: Perhaps you should use a library that knows how to parse and build query strings.

Comment: `.replace(/([?&])page=.*?(&|$)/,'$1')` simple enough :D

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Not so great if `?page=...` is the first param. Now you have a query string with no leading `?`

Comment: @PaulRoub I say it's simple and I still bugger it up. Realising my mistake, I added `$1` so that captured `?` or `&` is kept.

Answer (score 0):

That's quite easy... It's just `/page=\d+&?/`

```
var uri = '?name=John&page=12&mfgid=320';
uri = uri.replace(/page=\d+&?/,'');
```

Comment: `var uri = '?name=John&otherpage=abc&mfgid=210';` Oh dear.

Comment: I don't have any other parameters with the word "page" inside them. I would have stated that as a requirement if I did. So, @Reeno's answer does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
uri = uri.replace(/[?&]page=[^&\n]+$|([&?])page=[^&\n]+&/g, '$1');
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mH5mP0/1)

We'll need to use alternation to cover all the cases of presence of query parameter. Check my demo for all test cases.